# Android Application Startup Event

Tags: android, startup, android-event

I am looking for a possibility to monitor if a application gets started, i.e. if the user starts any app on his phone, my app should register that. Is there an easy way to achieve this? Such as an broadcast event?
I tried out to catch the `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED` event with a broadcast receiver, but it did not work. Is there a possibility to get notified if an application gets started? Such as the event `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` that is send out if an app got installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It's not possible, see [this mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/fNTysSA8mWQ).

Comment: well thanks, in this case i think, i keep a service that gets periodicaly woken up and scans the currently running processes. that requires a bit more work but should do it aswell.